# How to Ignore Blanks

Tags: excel

[image: Example Pic:]

Hi, I got the solution with helper column. Can I get answer without helper column as shown in the picture. Thanks in advance..

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: As shown the picture. If I select Red, all stadiums belongs to Red is my output. For getting the output I used Helper column. Can get solution dynamically without helper column. F5, F14 cells are dropdowns.

Comment: Use [`filter`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `SCAN()` function with `FILTER()`.

```
=FILTER(D6:D17,SCAN("",C6:C17,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b="",a&b,b)))=G6)
```

- Here `SCAN()` will generate an array filling empty cells with value of its above cell. Then just filter D column based on that array.

[image]

Comment: similar to my approach removing the names and using ranges: `=FILTER(B2:B5, SCAN("", A2:A5, LAMBDA(acc,tt, IF(acc="", tt, IF(tt="", acc, tt))))=D2)` but removing one `IF`, good point.

Comment: I was posting same time you posted the answer. Let is only efficient in case of repetitive use of same calculation. Simple approach always attracts visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Try this on cell `E2`, using `LET` for easy reading of the expression:

```
=LET(teams, A2:A5, names, B2:B5, dropDownValue, D2,
  helper, SCAN("", teams, LAMBDA(acc,tt, IF(acc="", tt, IF(tt="", acc, tt)))),
  FILTER(names, helper=dropDownValue)
)
```

or just using the ranges:

```
=FILTER(B2:B5,SCAN("",A2:A5,LAMBDA(acc,tt,IF(acc="",tt,IF(tt="",acc,tt))))=D2)
```

the idea is just to create the helper column on the fly via `SCAN` function. The rest is just to use `FILTER` function based on the drop-down value in cell `D2`. Here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

**Note**: Based on your sample data, it is assumed the first value of `teams` column is non-empty and with the color value.